# My nginx + fastcgi configuration downloads php files instead of executing them

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm using this configuration on a fresh install of php5-fpm and nginx on ubuntu 13.04:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But, my web browser is seeing php as text instead of the executed results.  Where should I look to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your php code is being displayed directly because it's not being sent to the php engine, that means the location block is being matched and the php file is being served, but the php file isn't being captured by the php block, so your problem is in the php block.

In that block you have 2 `fastcgi_pass`, one with a port (9000) and the other to a unix socket, you can't have both together, but since you've tagged your question with fastcgi so I'll assume you are using fastcgi, try commenting this line

```
#fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: That was strange.  I was able to see that fastcgi was running but I couldn't get php output using either line to connect.  I reinstalled everything and followed this guide (http://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx) and everything seems to be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting the wrong Content-Type header set. You can check this with various tools. For example, open the Developer Tools "Network" tab in Chrome, and then request the page. You'll see the "Content Type" returned in one of the columns, and you can click on the request in the left column to see the full Response headers. I suspect you'll find the header being returned is either "text/plain" or "application/octet-stream" instead of text/html, which is probably want you want.

Nginx usually sets a default Content-Type header based on the extension. This is done with the [types](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) directive, which I don't see mentioned above, so you may wish to check your settings there to confirm that the php extension is mapped to text/html. Explicitly setting a `Content-Type`header in your application may also help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating my nginx vhost by changing

`default_type  application/octet-stream;`

to

`default_type text/html;`